# SELECT records that contains just ENGLISH A - Z 1 -9 charachters

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7

I have a non English language website. Recently someone published a lot of English spammy topics.

I need a SQL statement to select topics that contains **only English** language.

Knowing that some of our original (not spammy) website topics contains some phrases in English we do not want to bring those for us.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `title` NOT LIKE '[^\x20-\x7E]'
```

The result was all posts.

For example:

1. "Where are you from?"    ---> Only English NOT ALLOWED
2. "من اين انت؟"                     ---> Only Arabic ALLOWED
3. "مامعنى كلمة where بالانكليزي"  --> English & Arabic ALLOWED

We just need to browse which like the no. 1 without results like no. 3

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL you can use [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

Like

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]+$';
```

Or if you need to exclude some letters

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$';
```

SQL Server has a [similar Expressio](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/ssms/scripting/search-text-with-regular-expressions?view=sql-server-ver15)n like2

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column NOT LIKE '%[^ ,.-~]%' collate Latin1_General_BIN
```

DEMO für ,ysql

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Demo (ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
> , Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
>      PRIMARY KEY (ID));
>
> INSERT INTO Demo (Name)
>
> SELECT '0123456789'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT '0.a'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT '0,a'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT '0éa'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT '0!a'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT '0?a'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT '0''a'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT '0#a'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT '0+a'
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Demo  WHERE Name REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$';
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Name                      
> -: | :-------------------------
>  1 | 0123456789                
>  2 | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>  3 | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM Demo
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Name                      
> -: | :-------------------------
>  1 | 0123456789                
>  2 | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>  3 | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
>  4 | 0.a                       
>  5 | 0,a                       
>  6 | 0éa                      
>  7 | 0!a                       
>  8 | 0?a                       
>  9 | 0'a                       
> 10 | 0#a                       
> 11 | 0+a
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7b2b7bd08eded27f24990997498dd29f)*

SQL SERVEr Example

> ```
> CREATE TABLE #Demo (ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)
> INSERT INTO #Demo (Name)
>
> SELECT '0123456789'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT '0.a'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT '0,a'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT '0éa'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT '0!a'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT '0?a'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT '0''a'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT '0#a'
>
> UNION ALL
>
> SELECT '0+a'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 11 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM #Demo WHERE Name NOT LIKE '%[^ ,.-~]%' collate Latin1_General_BIN
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Name                      
> -: | :-------------------------
>  1 | 0123456789                
>  2 | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>  3 | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
>  4 | 0.a                       
>  5 | 0,a                       
>  8 | 0?a
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM #Demo
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Name                      
> -: | :-------------------------
>  1 | 0123456789                
>  2 | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>  3 | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
>  4 | 0.a                       
>  5 | 0,a                       
>  6 | 0éa                      
>  7 | 0!a                       
>  8 | 0?a                       
>  9 | 0'a                       
> 10 | 0#a                       
> 11 | 0+a
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ee2dac8335c230de8744c190b3e65608)*

Comment: I am using MySQL Innodb ,this is the result that I get : Error
Static analysis:

2 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized keyword. (near "collate" at position 61)
Unexpected token. (near "Latin1_General_BIN" at position 69)
SQL query: Documentation

SELECT * FROM `qa_posts` WHERE `title` NOT LIKE '%[^ ,.-~]%' collate Latin1_General_BIN

MySQL said: Documentation

#1273 - Unknown collation: 'Latin1_General_BIN'

Comment: Use the mysql link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7b2b7bd08eded27f24990997498dd29f

Answer (score 1):

From a different approach:

```
SELECT ... WHERE HEX(col) REGEXP '^(..)*D[89B]'
```

Will find match rows with `col` containing at least one Arabic character in utf8 or utf8mb4.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this in SQL-server, which doesn't know regexp, translate could be handy.

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 20, @from varchar(128), @to varchar(128);

WHILE @cnt < 128
BEGIN
   set @from = concat(@from,nchar(@cnt))
   set @to = concat(@to,' ')
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;

select @from as sfrom, @to as sto;

select 'NOK' where len(trim(translate('les élèves',@from,@to))) > 0;
select 'OK' where len(trim(translate('the elves',@from,@to))) = 0;
```

Comment: Note that `TRANSLATE` was introduced in SQL Server 2017. The question is tagged with SQL Server 2012.